Unknown column 'unique' in 'field list' when i try to get data from mysql
router.get('/city/:id',CityController.get);

const get = async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        const response = cityService.getCity(req.params.id);
    
        return res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({
            data:response,
            success:true,
            message:"Successfully Fetched a city",
            error:{},
        });
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);

        return res.status(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
            data:{},
            success:false,
            message:"Not able to get the city",
            error:error,
        });
    }
}

  async getCity(id){
        try{    

            const city = await this.cityRepository.getCity(id);
            
            return city;

        }catch(error){
            console.log("Something went wrong at service layer");
            throw error;
        }
     }

 async getCity(id) {
    try {
      const city = await City.findByPk(id);
    
      return city;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw {error};
    }
  }

**
this is how implment logic for get data from cities one issue is that it shows in response in postman that
** { "data": {}, "success": true, "message": "Successfully Fetched a city", "error": {} }
this is the city model
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class City extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  City.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique:true,
    allowNull: false,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'City',
  });
  return City;
};

and this is migration
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Cities', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
        unique:true,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Cities');
  }
};

**
but i have error in terminal and also not getting data
i have tried with checking console where is the problem also check in database that i have created id as primary key**
this is the my problem if anyone can suggest what is the issue?

Can you share with us your error, please

Can you try adding await to const response = cityService.getCity(req.params.id);? So const response = await cityService.getCity(req.params.id);.

yes i have write that still it give me errror
"error": {
"name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
"parent": {
"code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
"errno": 1054,
"sqlState": "42S22",
"sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'unique' in 'field list'",
this is database
'id', 'int(11)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'11', 'delhi', '2024-05-29 09:18:36', '2024-05-29 09:18:36'

can you give as how you defined your model

using sequelize cli
i am updating in this code check if you can helo

please change model definition:
you was trying to get 'unique' column from your columns definition that doesn't exists
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class City extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  City.init({
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'City',
  });
  return City;
};

